# Python resources, community, magazine

Tags: python

I want to know python resources with actual information - news, articles, forum (english/USA - speaking). I learned python now (i have already good knowledge c/c++), and i need something more than official documentation/tutorial. I want to read about modern technics of python programming, popular and new frameworks/modules, optimization technics etc.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/111857/1052325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home website, www.python.org, has a collection of links to other resources including the [comp.lang.python newsgroup](http:////groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/topics), the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), and a [collection of major Python blog posts](http://blog.python.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I am an active member of a small but growing community called [python-forum](http://python-forum.org)